# ¿como mostrar en un div otra pagina segun el link de la pagina?

Tags: php, html, div

Estoy haciendo una web donde hice un formulario donde al enviarlo me crea un archivo nuevo php, tengo una plantilla donde en un div muestro el contenido del archivo nuevo creado, lo estoy haciendo con un iframe me carga bien y todo, pero el problema que tengo es q quiero que esa plantilla me cargue en el iframe el contenido del archivo que yo quiera, me explico, quiero que por el link para abrir la pagina me cargue el iframe que yo quiera, si pongo `www.mipagina.com/iframe?iframe1` me aparezca el `iframe 1` si pongo `www.mipagina.com/iframe?iframe2` me cargue el `iframe 2` asi sucesivamente, ósea quiero que desde una sola pagina pueda cargar todos los iframes pero con un link que me abra el iframe que yo quiera, que NO me toque entrar primero a la pagina y lego escoger el `iframe`. o si me pueden dar alguna otra sugerencia para lograr esto, no es necesariamente con iframes Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se pretende es capturar el valor que viene por petición  `GET` *(?iframe=iframe1)* para luego validar y saber que contenido se mostrará.

Para obtener el valor de dichas variables existe [$_GET['parametro']](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php), en tu ejemplo para obtener el valor de `iframe` `www.mipagina.com/iframe?iframe1` sería `$_GET['iframe']` donde `iframe` será el `parámetro` enviado por URL

**Ejemplo Completo**

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    if(isset($_GET['iframe'])){
      $parametro= htmlspecialchars($_GET['iframe']);
       switch ($parametro) {
         case 'iframe1':
           echo "iframe1" ;
           break;
        case 'iframe2':
           echo "iframe2" ;
           break;
        default:
           break;
       }
     }
   } 
 ?>
```

Sobre el `SRC` del `iframe` recibido por parametro sería ya sin un `switch`

```
<?php 
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    if(isset($_GET['iframe'])){
     $parametro= htmlspecialchars($_GET['iframe']);
       echo "<iframe src='$parametro'></iframe>"
   }
}
```

Comment: De esta manera al escribir en la barra de link www.mipagina.com/iframe.php?iframe1 me cargaria el iframe 1? y si cambio el 1 por el dos me cargaria el iframe 2? así sucesivamente?

Comment: el iframe solo tendra un src donde este cambie segun el link que se ponga en la barra de direcciones, se podria así? tomar despues del signo de pregunta la ruta de donde se encuentra el archivo y este se agrege al src, es posible hacer eso? es que son muchas paginas.

Comment: @Stivents si , dicho valor lo almacenas en la variable `$parametro`

Comment: Aun no he entendido bien :/ pues si se que el valor lo almaceno en $parametro pero aun no se como capturar la ruta es la parte que no he entendido, si el link es www.mipagina.com/iframe.php?iframe1.php como capturo la ruta que esta despues del signo de pregunta, para almacenarlo en el parametro.

Comment: Por lo general después del signo de pregunta va un nombre o valor con el cual obtenemos desde php. En tu ejemplo era `www.mipagina.com/iframe.php?iframe=estevalortendralavariableparametro` y lo que va después ya estará en tu variable parámetro(en mi ejemplo)

Comment: Ahora si entendi, muchas gracias, ahora si puedo terminar mi proyecto esto me tenia detenido le agradesco. Y lo siento por mi ignoracia en codigo y gracias por el tiempoo que se tomo para explicarme :)